# How to set the FK in the child entityto null after deleting a pernt entity in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have my category entity as shown below. A category can have many children categories or none. I want a solution where I can delete a parent category, and if this parent has children categories, I want to set the FK in these children to NULL.

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonBackReference
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName = "category_id")
    private Category parentCategory;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="parentCategory", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Category> childCategories = new ArrayList<Category>();

    public List<Category> getChildCategories() {
       return childCategories;
    }

    public void setParentCategory(Category parentCategory) {
       this.parentCategory = parentCategory;
    }
```

I have tried the below solution but it doesn't work:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;


public void delete(String id) throws Exception{
    try {
        Category parent = this.findById(id);
        for(Category child : parent.getChildCategories()){
            child.setParentCategory(null);
            this.em.merge(child);
        }
        this.em.remove(parent);
    }catch (TransactionalException ex){
        throw new Exception("There is no transaction for this entity manager");
    }
}
```

Comment: could you specify the undesired outcome, "does not work" says rather little.

Comment: The approach you are using is risky. Do not set child category to nul. What if you deleted by mistake and want to revert? What I suggest is. have a common field called is_deleted.   Whenever you delete any parent, in service class, have two logics 1 - iterate over all childs and set is_deleted to true. 2 - Set is_deleted for parent to true. Now, in your entity class add a where condition that only records with is-deleted=false are returned.

Comment: Let me know if you need a sample code

Comment: @SridharPatnaik sample code will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Create a mapped super class with reusable fields to be used in every entity

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Audited
public class ReusableFields implements Serializable
{

    public static final String SOFT_DELETED_CLAUSE = "is_deleted = 'false'";

    
    @Column(name="is_deleted", columnDefinition="BOOLEAN DEFAULT true")
    public boolean isDeleted;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    @JsonProperty("created")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ")
    private Date created;
    
    
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    @JsonProperty("updated")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Date modified;

//getter setter
```

In your entities, add a where clause to exclude deleted records

Parent - Category entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Category")
@Audited
@Where(clause = ReusableFields.SOFT_DELETED_CLAUSE)
public class Category extends ReusableFields
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    Long categoryId;
    
    @NonNull
    @JsonDeserialize(using = ToTitleCaseDeserializer.class)
    @Column(name="category_name")
    String categoryName;
    
    @JsonDeserialize(using = ToSentenceCaseDeserializer.class)
    String categoryDescription;
//Gettersetter
}
```

Child - Product Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Product")
@Audited
@Where(clause = ReusableFields.SOFT_DELETED_CLAUSE)
public class Product extends ReusableFields
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    Long productId;
    
    @NonNull
    @Column(name="product_name")
    String productName;
    
    String productDescription;
    
    String measurementUnit;
    
    Double reorderQuantity;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="categoryId",nullable=false)
    Category category;
```

Add a softdelete repository and delete method to mark any record as deleted

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T, ID> extends JpaRepository<T, ID>
{


    default void softDelete(T entity) {

        Assert.notNull(entity, "The entity must not be null!");
        Assert.isInstanceOf(ReusableFields.class, entity, "The entity must be soft deletable!");

        ((ReusableFields)entity).setDeleted(true);
        save(entity);
    }

    default void softDeleteById(ID id) {

        Assert.notNull(id, "The given id must not be null!");
        this.softDelete(findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new EmptyResultDataAccessException(
                String.format("No %s entity with id %s exists!", "", id), 1)));
    }


}
```

Extend this repository to your actual repository

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepo extends BaseRepository<Product, Long>
{
}
```

Now in your category service class, fetch all products linked to category you want to delete. Then iterate over product list and soft delete them. Then softdelete category.

```
public void deleteCategory(Long id) throws Exception 
    {
List<Product> products = pRepo.findByCategoryId(id);
for(Product product: products)
{
productRepo.softDeleteById(product.getProductId());
}
            categoryRepo.softDeleteById(id);
    }
```